# Invariant Violation in React Render OR the proper way to iterate and return in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm running into persistent problems in my React renders.

This code

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var AnswerRows = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
  },
  render: function() {
    {this.props.answers.map(function(answer, i) {
      return (
        <div id="answerRow">
          <label className="AnswerText">
            <input type="checkbox" value={answer.id}  />
            {answer.text}
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    }, this)}
  }
});

var QuizTaking = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="card-holder">
        <div className="showQuestionCard x-card host">
          <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.question.text}}></h3>
          <div className="answerRows">
            <AnswerRows answers={this.props.question.answers}/>
          </div>
          <div className='submitAnswers'></div>
        </div>
        <div className="paper-shadow-bottom"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Will give me `Invariant Violation: AnswerRows.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.` errors.  However, this works every time:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var TestIndex = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
  },
  loadTest: function(i) {
    window.location.replace(this.props.tests[i].url.replace(".json", "/take"))
  },

  render: function () {
    return(
      <div className="testTable card-holder">
        <div className="card-contents">
          {this.props.tests.map(function(test, i) {
            return (
              <div className="testTableRow x-card host" key={test.id}>
                <label className="__TITLE">{test.title}
                  <button onClick={this.loadTest.bind(test, i)}  key={i} type="button" className="StartButton paper-button raisedButton">Start this test</button>
                </label>
                <div className="paper-shadow-bottom"></div>
              </div>
            );
          }, this)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

I'd really like to understand what is going on here, and perhaps the 'right' way to do it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot return multiple elements (like the array returned by the map function) from the render function. Also, you're missing a return statement. Try this:

```
var AnswerRows = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.answers.map(function(answer, i) {
          return (
            <div id="answerRow">
              <label className="AnswerText">
                <input type="checkbox" value={answer.id}  />
                {answer.text}
              </label>
            </div>
          );
        }, this)}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the last line inside the div? why is this being passed in to map?

Comment: Please explain further. I'm running into this exact problem and don't fully understand the solution.

Comment: @monkeyjumps this is to ensure that the value of `this` inside the function that is passed to map is the same as the value of `this` inside the render function. Refer to the documentation of map for more details https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @sweeds ensure that you are returning exactly one node in the render function. You cannot return an array of multiple nodes. If you want to do this, you have to wrap it in another element such as the `div` in the solution I gave.