# ReactJS - Error while loading data from json file

Tags: json, reactjs

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React component</title>
    <script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="myContent"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
    var ChatMessagesLists = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: {chat_messages:[]}};
    },
    render: function(){
        return
            (
                <div className="chatLstsWrapper">
                <h1>Chat Messages</h1>
                <ChatMessagesData data={this.state.data} />
                </div>
            )
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'jsontextfile.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                     this.setState({data: {chat_messages:[]}});
                }
            });
    }
    });

    var ChatMessagesData = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        console.log(this.props.data.chat_messages);
        return(
            <ul className="chatLsts">
                {
                    this.props.data.chat_messages.map(function(chatmessages){
                        return <li>{chatmessages.from_account_id}</li>
                    })
                }
                </ul>
        )
    }
    })

    React.render(<ChatMessagesLists />,document.getElementById("myContent"));

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>


JSON File
{
    "message": "List of chat messages",
    "data": {
        "since_index": 1,
        "before_index": 2,
        "chat_messages": [
            {
                "text": "Load more",
                "type": "text",
                "key": "8ff134e7-e302-445b-903e-0038097c8a29"
            },
            {
                "text": "my test data",
                "type": "text",
                "key": "3c7c3065-3701-4350-a64a-8a52f9fe1578"
            },
            {
                "text": "My message",
                "type": "text",
                "key": "40f7c342-a019-44c3-ad2b-8b2ae018972b"
            }
        ],
    "max_results": 20
    },
}
```

While loading the data getting below error. Can anyone please suggest where am i wrong

**Error: Invariant Violation: ChatMessagesLists.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.**

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

Have you tried:

```
 var ChatMessagesData = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
     var items = this.props.data.chat_messages.map(function(chatmessages){
       return <li>{chatmessages.from_account_id}</li>;
      })
    return(
        <ul className="chatLsts">
            {
              items  
            }
        </ul>
    );
});
```

PS: In Ajax callback, you not update the state:

```
success: function(data){
    this.setState({data: {chat_messages: data}});
}
```

Comment: Hi Jean, <br /> The issue still exists. Please help

Comment: The JSON file is response of ajax request ? Because I don't see `from_account_id` properties

Comment: sorry i actually had changed the property. But you can try with any other property which i have specified above say "type", "text" or "key". The same error still exists

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26430757/invariant-violation-in-react-render-or-the-proper-way-to-iterate-and-return-in-r)

Comment: I am unable to get it. Could you please explain what are you trying to convey?